# Java: How can I get the UNC path from a path containing the drive letter?

Tags: java, path, unc

I'm quite new in programming in Java and I am looking for a possibility to
get a UNC path from a path containing the drive letter.

*Example:
I want to get from: "Z:\folder1\folder2\file.xyz" to "\\aabbcc\abc\def\folder1\folder2\file.xyz".*

The drive is mapped with this letter on the PC running this code so it should be possible to get to the UNC path, shouldn't it?

Thank you very much for your support!

Juergen

Comment: ProcessBuilder for the Windows **net use Z:** I am afraid.

Comment: Thank you Joop and sorry for my late response! Let's see if I can solve it.